# I can't get the sheetnames function to work in openpyxl

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

Hope I'm not duplicating threads here. Had a good look and can't find anyone else having the same issue.

I'm using the latest version of openpyxl (downloaded and installed using pip today!)

All I am trying to do is call the sheetnames in a particular excel file and, no matter what I try, the sheetnames function will not work.

The error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/JeremyAinley/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/xlsx reader/get sheetnames.py", line 9, in <module>
sheetnames = wb.sheetnames
AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'sheetnames'
```

Here is my code:

```
import openpyxl
import os
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook


wb = load_workbook(r'C:\Users\Jeremy\Desktop\FilesZ\PDT.xlsx')
sheetnames = wb.sheetnames
print(sheetnames)
ws = wb.active
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: You've reassigned `wb` to be the active worksheet. Try `ws = wb.active`

Comment: Hi Charlie, thanks for replying I have reassigned as you suggested and it's still throwing up the same error

Comment: I've edited the code.

Answer (score 1):

As was suggested in the comments, your problem here is that you're assigning `wb.active` to `wb`, which would mean that `wb` was no longer a workbook but rather the active sheet on said workbook. To fix this, we just have to rename our variables:

```
import openpyxl
import os
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook(r'C:\Users\Jeremy\Desktop\FilesZ\PDT.xlsx')
active_workbook = wb.active
names = wb.sheetnames
print(names)
```

Comment: No brackets required, it's a property.

Comment: @CharlieClark Yeah, I saw the parentheses around it in their docs and assumed :/

Comment: That's the reference to the method that gets wrapped as a property.

Answer (score 0):

If you created the python program filename same with 'openpyxl.py', you will got clashing, please can make another program filename instead of 'openpyxl.py'.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. The error message occurs on "get sheetnames.py" on the line "wb.sheetnames"